# What is the Record-Score Setter medal awarded for?

Tags: splatoon-3

While playing Rainmaker in Anarchy Battle, I noticed I'd won medals for both #1 Score Booster and Record-Score Setter in a single round. Presumably the Score Booster medal is for boosting the team score, so what is the Record-Score Setter medal for?

[image: #1 Score Booster and Record-Score Setter in one round]

Comment: Score booster is an award for object score (Tower Control, Rainmaker, Clam Blitz) according to this [website](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/all-multiplayer-medals-in-splatoon-3-and-what-they-mean), I (and the website) don't know about record setter but I guess highest point you've achieved in the game or with a weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record-score Setter is awarded in Tower Control when you ride the tower closest to the enemy team's goal point. I'd assume that it is very similar in Rainmaker, being awarded when you bring the Rainmaker closest to the enemy base from your team.